# Find the product of consecutive natural numbers raised to a power.

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

Is there any direct formula for calculating the product of a finite series of consecutive integers?

I want to calculate
101$^{199}$$*$102$^{197}$$*$103$^{195}$....198$^5$$*$199$^3$

Comment: You might want to use a calculator.

Comment: This is actually part of a statement I'm trying to prove

Comment: What is your statement? Because there is apparently no way to give a closed form for this product.

Comment: Also, isnt't your series missing a 197?

Comment: I need to prove that the product of the factorials of first 400 natural numbers when divided by 200 factorial gives a perfect square.

Comment: Yes thankyou updated it

Comment: It is also missing a 200 :).

Comment: no I need it upto 199 only my solution is almost done now I just need to prove that this series is a perfect square

Comment: That's going to be rather difficult, since the prime number $101$ Is a factor, but $101^2$ isn't.

Comment: $n!/(n-m)!$....

Answer (score 0):

You can express it as a ratio of factorials.  If you want the numbers from $a$ through $b$ inclusive, it is $\frac{b!}{(a-1)!}$ because the denominator takes out all the ones below $a$.  The statement in the comments that $\frac{400!}{200!}$ is a square is not correct.  Take any prime in the range $(200,399)$.  It divides the fraction exactly once, so the fraction is not a perfect square.  The same proof works any time there is a prime in the range $[\max (\frac b2,a+1),b]$

Comment: No he statement is that the product of the factorials of first 400 natural numbers when divived by 200! give a perfect  square

Comment: Well, if you write $400! \times 399! \times 398! \times ... \times 1!$ as $400^1\times 399^2\times 398^3\times 397^4\times ... \times 1^{400}$, you can take out a huge square factor $400^0\times 399^2\times 398^2\times 397^4\times ... \times 1^{400}$, then you only have to prove that $400\times398\times396\times ... \times 2$ is a square times $200!$.

Comment: @MichaelHartley:  The question has been edited since I answered.  There were no powers there when I responded.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(n)=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{2n} k!}{n!}$.
Then $$\tag1f(n+1)=f(n)\cdot \frac{(2n+2)!(2n+1)!}{n+1}=f(n)\cdot2\cdot (2n+1)!^2$$
and in particular $\frac{f(n+2)}{f(n)}$ is a perfect square.

Or: By induction using $(1)$ and $f(0)=1$, we have that $\sqrt{2^{-n}f(n)}$ is an integer for all $n$.